# WebMethod access page control and set value

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

My page name

```
public partial class AtamaGorevDegistir : System.Web.UI.Page
{}
```

My webmethod ajax side

```
var path = getLocation(location.href);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path.pathname + "/KisiBilgiDoldur",
    //  data: "{" + str + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //  dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var dd = data.d;
        $('.modal-dialog').css({ width: '85%' });
        $('#AtamaModal').modal({ show: true });
    }
});
```

My webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string KisiBilgiDoldur(string KayitID, string TeklifID)
{
   AtamaGorevDegistir atama = new AtamaGorevDegistir();
   atama.AtananSuren.Value = "123";
   return null;
}
```

But my problem my Control is null  . But i can access this method but didnt set value and give error message. Why this happened?

Comment: send paramters with data. Your data is comment.

Answer (score 1):

WebMethod and ScriptMethod can't access the controls collection of the calling page. Think of it as outside the normal Web Forms lifecycle. When you use AJAX, you need to pass all data to the server side method it needs, and your server side should return all data that the client side needs. Then the client side should take that returned data and manipulate the DOM as necessary to display the result.

In your WebMethod, return the data instead of trying to assign it to a control, remove the `return null;`.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string KisiBilgiDoldur(string KayitID, string TeklifID)
{
   return "123";
}
```

In your client side success handler, get the returned data and set the value of the control using JavaScript.

```
var path = getLocation(location.href);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path.pathname + "/KisiBilgiDoldur",
    //  data: "{" + str + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //  dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var dd = data.d;
        $('.modal-dialog').css({ width: '85%' });
        $('#AtamaModal').modal({ show: true });
        //set control value to data.d here
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this method and using but my question dont about this . I want to access  control  because i using so mix componet and i didnt set client side . I need server side set .

Comment: @smtprld But that's not how it works. Saying you want it to work that way doesn't change how it works.

Comment: this way not work for me . Because i dont want to this because return so delay for me . I will using therad and faster work for big data . İf you are profesyonel you know . And i can using ashx etc. You know How to access page control in webmethod or etc way . I dont ask you How to work ajax . I ask how to access page control and set . If you know , dont know . Dont say me how to work .

Comment: @smtp I am "professional". I am paid to write code, and I've been doing it for a while now. If you did understand AJAX, Web Forms control lifecycle, and how WebMethod works, you would understand that what you're asking for is not actually possible, and I have given you a viable workaround. If you choose not to listen, that's fine. But why ask a question here if you don't want to listen to the answer? Whether you like it or not, it doesn't change the reality of how the web works.

Comment: you are legend . U know eveything . And listen your answer . You dont want to understand me . But its not my answer understand.

Comment: @smtp I'm not saying I know everything. But I'm saying I do have a solid foundation of knowledge when it comes to how AJAX and WebMethod works, and it's enough knowledge to tell me what you're asking for simply isn't possible. If you think I'm wrong on that, feel free to point it where I'm wrong. But three different people have told you now that you can't access the Controls collection from WebMethod.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the control value with a webmethod.  Your return a value and from the api and do something with it, in the browser.  Working with webmethods are not like webforms.  The value you return in your webmethod is null... you're setting that null value into 'dd' in js, but you don't do anything with it.  When you get your value back from the webmethod you need to do something with it.  try 'alert(data.d)' in your success callback to see what i mean.  Then $('#elm').text(data.d) if you want it on the page.

Comment: I know using return data.d  but i am using devexpress control and i need server side that do it

Comment: get the id of the devexpress control and use the devexpress clientside functionality to populate it with the value returned by the webmethod

Comment: Problem not is . Question so easy How to access page control in Webmethod ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it the way you want to.  See @mason's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add parameters to data.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path.pathname + "/KisiBilgiDoldur",
        data:JSON.stringify({ KayitID: '1', TeklifID:'2' }), 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var dd = data.d;

            $('.modal-dialog').css({ width: '85%' });
            $('#AtamaModal').modal({ show: true });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bro please read my webmethod i am sending parametre but isnt my problem i want to access control and set value.

Comment: @smtprld Let's no "bro" people here. Not everyone isn't a male, and not everyone appreciates being called that. Your lines for passing parameters are commented out in your question.